# send push notification to device directly from a device swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any way to send push notification from a device to device directly using https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send.

My code:

```
func sendPushNotification(toUser: String, message: String) {
    let urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let paramString  = "to="

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)  { (data, response, error) in
        do {
            if let jsonData = data {
                if let jsonDataDict  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    NSLog("Received data:\n\(jsonDataDict))")
                }
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: You never use `toUser` function parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let paramString  = ["to" : FCM_ID/UDID, "notification" : ["title" : NOTIFICATION_TITLE, "body" : NOTIFICATION_BODY], "data" : ["user" : USER_ID, "image" : IMAGE_URL, "extrainfo" : ANY_STRING]]
```

just replace your line with this one and push notification should deliver.

Read more about it here... https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: can u please help me with how to create NOTIFICATION_BODY

Comment: Its just a simple string. It is the message that shows up on the notification banner below the title. Everything in caps is just a string that you need to replace.

Comment: i want to send some contents inside the body like image url, user id

Comment: Then you need to add data key value also. Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: how and where to include our server authorization key??

Comment: push body {
    data =     {
        audioUrl = "";
        desc = noti;
        endTime = "22-09-2017 11:45:45";
        imgUrl = "";
        location = chennai;
        startTime = "21-09-2017 11:45:38";
        timenumber = 1379;
        title = push;
    };
    notification =     {
        body = noti;
        title = push;
    };
    to = "eylR3hervg0:APA91bHmMnY8ZSutyQp-K5s3-u5NzTiLxsGkQBku1t3lZSuzM9rGiQFT0WKv7A4KrqOWpIJVuRyRPPmNVldsxHLolXRGZBXHigdf4Tfn_BTPW0buedNpGq1R5icuJAZ3H734YeMNCSeh";
}

Comment: this is my payload and i get UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154861/discussion-between-mohanraj-and-prateek-varshney).

Answer (score -1):

Old post but it's worth to add to accepted solution as it can be helping others.  You can check my post [Push Notifications are delivered but didReceiveRemoteNotification is never called Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376255/push-notifications-are-delivered-but-didreceiveremotenotification-is-never-calle/56382289#56382289) or here [didReceiveRemoteNotification function doesn't called with FCM notification server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801107/didreceiveremotenotification-function-doesnt-called-with-fcm-notification-serve/56381878#56381878). 
You must have `"content_available": true`in your notification definition or push notification service(with underscore) or your `didReceiveRemoteNotification` won't be called and you won't be able to use `userInfo`.